# Why did USB stop working suddenly?

Tags: usb, devices

I tried to connect an Amazon Kindle (as I do everyday) to my 3rd. USB port, as the other two are always busy with mouse and keyboard.

When I connected the device, the computer froze and I eventually had to boot the hard way. However, when I reloaded Ubuntu, the all three USB ports weren't woking anymore. They won't respond when I connect mouse/keyboard/Kindle/massive storage device or whatever, although the ports still provide power (mouse light is on and massive storage device vibrates as if it were working).

What can I do with that? I am using a 6-month-old Samsung RV511, even though I am not sure if it matters all. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please open a terminal window and enter the command `lsusb`, then add the output from that command to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me, too.  I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.  I had a mouse, keyboard, and external USB hard drive plugged in.  Then, when I also plugged in my iPhone via USB, my computer froze.  When I rebooted, no USB devices were registering anything being connected to them:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

After unplugging all my USB devices (expect for my keyboard and mouse, which are low-power devices), I restarted my computer a couple of times.  Then, my USB devices started working again.

Once the USB devices started working again, `lsusb` gave me the following output:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 413c:2106 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0461:4d22 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So, I suggest unplugging all USB devices and cycling your computer a couple of times.  The best way to do this is to log in to your computer remotely via ssh and enter the command `sudo shutdown -r now`.  Do this a few times.